# Ошибка при компиляции класса: нет подходящего конструктора по умолчанию

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

Есть данный код:

```
class Neuron  // Neuron of the NNW
    {
    private:
        std::vector<double> Wheights;  // Wheights of Inputs
        double Output = 0;

        double delta  = 0;

    public:
        Neuron(int InputCount)
        {
            Wheights.resize(InputCount);  // Set the size of vector
            for (std::vector<double>::iterator n = Wheights.begin(); n != Wheights.end(); ++n)
                *n = rand() / (RAND_MAX / 2.0) - 1.0;  // Changes all values to random number  (from 1.0 to -1.0)
        }

        void FeedFoward(std::vector<double> Inputs)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)Wheights.size(); i++)
                sum += Wheights.at(i) * Inputs.at(i);

            Output = 1 / (1 + exp(-sum));
        }
    };

class Lier  // Lier of the NNW
    {
    private:
        std::vector<Neuron> Neurons;  // Massiv with Neurons in Lier

    public:
        Lier(int NeuronCount, int InputCount = 0)
        {
            Neurons.resize(NeuronCount);  // Set the size of vector
            for (std::vector<Neuron>::iterator n = Neurons.begin(); n != Neurons.end(); ++n)
                *n = Neuron(InputCount);  // Fill the vector with neurons 
        }
    };
```

При попытке сделать сборку пишет что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Объясните что не так, такая ошибка вылезает часто, решаю обычно просто заново переписав код но что здесь не так понять не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, в

```
Neurons.resize(NeuronCount);
```

вы хотите изменить размер вектора. Чем он должен быть заполнен? Элементами `Neuron` по умолчанию, "пустыми", так сказать. Но у вас можно создавать `Neuron` только от `int`:

```
Neuron(int InputCount)
```

Вот компилятор и сообщает вам, что он не в состоянии ничего сделать без конструктора по умолчанию...

Каким именно он должен быть - вам виднее...

Comment: Да, это помогло. Думал что он заполняет все пустые ячейки значением Null типа Neuron

Comment: Такого не бывает :) Это же не указатель... Если ответ устроил - принимайте (птичка слева)...